# IdentityServer4 Single Sign On with different scopes

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, openid, identityserver4

Scenario: 
b2c app  with scope1 and scope2
b2b app with scope3 and scope4

Issue: 
A user who can access both sites. If the user logs in on the b2b he will not have the b2c scope. So going to the b2c site the login will not be re-proposed but the jwt token will not have the scopes to call the Api of that context.

Is there a way to request additional scopes on a logged in user? Unfortunately I didn't find anything on the documentation.

Thanks for your help

Comment: A user has nothing to do with scopes. A scope is a client (app) thing: it defines which (parts of) resources are accessable by the client. If b2c needs either scope3 or scope4 then this should be configured for the client.

Comment: Yes i know,  i ask how to handle a session that not have all the scopes required. The user is logged, so the identityserver skip the login page 
 the application have a valid jwt token that not have all the necessary scopes. So for exemple the call of the contex api  will return 401.

Comment: IdentityServer may skip the login page, but does create a new session and responds with a new access token for this site, containing all necessary claims based on the scopes of that client. So there shouldn't be an issue with scopes or claims.